# About algorithm analysis/performance?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, code-analysis

[image]

As show in the picture I have following structures to store set of closet "Curves" in a "Slice".
A "Curve"  consist of "Nodes" implemented as a doubly-linked-list.

Here is the psuedo code :

```
class Slice {
 List<Curve*> curves;
}

class Curve {
 int objectID;
 Node *headNode;
}

class Node {
 double x,
 double y,
 Node *next;
 Node *previous
}
```

I render this stucture using QT paint methods and I want to select the node closest to the mouse point.

What I do is,

a).Get each "Curve" in the "Slice"

b).Go through all nodes in selected curve and calculate the distance from mouse-point to each point and compare.

My questions :

1) if we take number of curve is "c" and average nodes is "n" the algorithm complexity is O(n*c). 
   Is this analysis correct?

2)Is there anyway to improve the algorithm ,make it more faster?  Using Binary Tree,HashTable ..etc?

Comment: One simple trick is to keep track of the diameter of a bounding circle for each curve. If any point on the curve's distance to the mouse point is further from the mouse point by more than two times the diameter, you can skip the other nodes on that curve. (If your closest point so far is 3 units from the mouse point and a curve with a bounding circle of 10 units has its first point 25 units from the mouse point, you can ignore the other nodes on that curve.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes your analysis is correct

2) You can get logarithmic complexity by using the [**nearest neighbor search**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) algorithms.

The simplest of all is perhaps [using the k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search)